# Show that every eigenvalue to a unitary operator has absolute value 1

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, unitary-matrices

Let $A$ be a unitary operator on hilbert space $H$, i.e.
$$(Au|Av) = (u|v)$$
for all $u,v \in D_A.$.

I'm asked to show that all eigenvalues to this unitary operator has absolute value 1.

My attempt:

Let u,v be eigenvectors to $A$ and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ their eigenvalues.

$$(Au|Av) = (\lambda_1u|\lambda_2v) = \lambda_1\lambda_2 (u|v) = (u|v) \implies \lambda_1\lambda_2=1.$$

For the statement to be true, $\lambda_1$ must equal $\lambda_2$ but I can't see why this is true. What am I missing?

Comment: Hint: try considering only 1 eigenvector at a time instead of 2.

Comment: also don't forget that if you're Hilbert space is a complex vector space then the inner product is *conjugate* linear in the second argument.

Comment: @user293794 Thanks I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda$ and eigenvalue of $A$. With $u$ his eigenvector.

Then $(u,u) = (Au,Au) = (\lambda u, \lambda u) = \lambda\overline{\lambda}(u,u) = |\lambda|^{2}(u,u)$

Thus $|\lambda|^{2} = 1 \implies |\lambda| = 1$